# How to match the images using regex?

Tags: php

Using regex, how can I get the image from the following?
I am trying `preg_match_all("!<img src='(.*?)' alt>!is", $str, $images);` without any luck

```
<div class="film_img">
    <a href="url"><img src="image url" alt="text"></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your pattern will fail because there is no `>` right after `alt`.

Comment: Oh, also, you have double quotes in the HTML and single quotes in your pattern.